# spring-boot testing - Could multiple test have a single context?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit-runner

I have integration tests, that i want use single context.

I know that all test initialize different beans therefore Spring restart on each tests. ( addded @DirtiesContext) But it's don't work?

My parent class -

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringApplicationContext.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class AbstractSpringITest {
}
```

Application context -

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.datas_tech.ingo.core")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class SpringApplicationContext {
}
```

Example tests -

```
public class MailServiceITest extends AbstractSpringITest {

    @Autowired
    public MailService mailService;
    ...

public class UserServiceITest extends AbstractSpringITest {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;
    ...
```

My console like this, when i start integration test for all tests

```
Running com.datas_tech.ingo.core.repository.log.LogRepositoryITest

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-07-19 17:27:58.613  INFO 4104 --- [           main] c.d.i.c.r.log.LogRepositoryITest         : Starting LogRepositoryITest on artur-pc with PID 4104 (started by artur in /home/artur/IdeaProjects/IngoX/core)
2017-07-19 17:27:58.614  INFO 4104 --- [           main] c.d.i.c.r.log.LogRepositoryITest         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-19 17:28:00.213  INFO 4104 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-07-19 17:28:00.223  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2017-07-19 17:28:00.490  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:00.492  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:00.495  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:00.498  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:00.544  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:00.658  INFO 4104 --- [           main] c.d.i.c.r.log.LogRepositoryITest         : Started LogRepositoryITest in 2.221 seconds (JVM running for 13.261)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 6.895 sec - in com.datas_tech.ingo.core.repository.log.LogRepositoryITest
Running com.datas_tech.ingo.core.repository.ldap.GroupRepositoryITest

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-07-19 17:28:05.629  INFO 4104 --- [           main] c.d.i.c.r.ldap.GroupRepositoryITest      : Starting GroupRepositoryITest on artur-pc with PID 4104 (started by artur in /home/artur/IdeaProjects/IngoX/core)
2017-07-19 17:28:05.629  INFO 4104 --- [           main] c.d.i.c.r.ldap.GroupRepositoryITest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-07-19 17:28:06.908  INFO 4104 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-07-19 17:28:06.918  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2017-07-19 17:28:07.184  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:07.188  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:07.190  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:07.192  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:07.231  INFO 4104 --- [           main] org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper                : Initializing a new instance of dozer bean mapper.
2017-07-19 17:28:07.406  INFO 4104 --- [           main] c.d.i.c.r.ldap.GroupRepositoryITest      : Started GroupRepositoryITest in 1.878 seconds (JVM running for 20.009)
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.902 sec - in com.datas_tech.ingo.core.repository.ldap.GroupRepositoryITest
Running com.datas_tech.ingo.core.repository.ldap.UserRepositoryITest
```

How do that all test use single context?

What's wrong?

Thanks